# Not able to populate second UITableView Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

**I'm unable to populate the second UITableView Controller, wondering if anyone could help.**

I'm using a websites API, JSON, and RestKit for the data.  I believe that part is working fine because my first VC loads fine.

But I'm not sure if I need to use prepareForSegue and/or didSelectRowAtIndexPath so that I can identify the cell/row selected in the first VC, so that the second VC populates with the (correct) data.

**1st VC populates correct:**

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return sports.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    Sport *sport = [sports objectAtIndex:section];
    return sport.leagues.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    Sport *sport = [sports objectAtIndex:section];
    return sport.name;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Sport *sport = [sports objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    League *league = [sport.leagues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = league.name;

    return cell;
}
```

**2nd VC populates blank table:**

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return leagues.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    League *league  = [leagues objectAtIndex:section];
    return league.teams.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    League *league = [leagues objectAtIndex:section];
    return league.name;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    League *league = [leagues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    Team *team = [league.teams objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = team.name;

    return cell;
}
```

**Or if I try to add extra code for 1st VC, app crashes before getting to 2nd VC:**

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TeamsViewController *teamsViewController = [[TeamsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TeamsViewController" bundle:nil];
    teamsViewController.title = [[sports objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"sports"];

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"leagueDetail"]) {
        TeamsViewController *tvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        tvc.data = [self.navigationController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row]
}
```

Would **really** appreciate any help!

Comment: In your second view controller, where were you setting `leaugues`? Try log your `leagues.count` and `league.teams.count`.

Comment: @Hari I'm not totally sure if this is what you meant, but I NSLog'd what you suggested on the first VC when I select the League "NBA" cell/row.  And it logs "National Basketball Association" which is correct league.name, but it logs "0" for leagues.count, and league.teams.count (which makes sense for league.teams.count because the team would be selected on the Second VC).  I'm not able to try any NSLog on the Second VC because so far all I've been able to get is a blank table or have the app crash at that point.  Does that help at all?  Appreciate the response alot!

Comment: So if leagues.count is 0, then how the table populated on second vc? You are returning leagues.count in numberOfSectionsInTableView for second vc,rt?. Also, I think you should set the `leagues` in your second vc from 1st vc on didSelectRowAtIndexPath. like `teamsViewController.leagues` = selected league data.

Comment: @Hari the table is not populating on the second VC.  Thats the problem I'm running into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little bit confused with excepting of creation UITableViewCell object. When you ask table view for dequeuing cell it returns one which it does not need at the moment, if there are no unused cell you have to create a new one. Try code like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Create cell
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d", indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Is that for the First VC or Second VC?  And is that just so the app doesn't crash on me?  Or will that also help with the passing of data from the First VC to the Second VC, which I'm assuming is the other problem that is possibly happening.

Comment: Snippet above is code I usually use in my VCs, so I meant you should use it in both your VCs.